# creating a gaussian mixture with defined properties

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am interesting in creating a mixture of gaussians with defined properties for mean, stdev, skewness, and kurtosis. My thought was to figure out the expressions for each of these descriptive statistics and then solve for the values of $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, and $p$ ($p$ = proportion of density in first gaussian). This was my approach:

First define the moments for the gaussian mixture:
$$
M1 = p \mu_1 + (1 - p) \mu_2\\
M2 = p (\mu_1^2 + \sigma_1^2) + (1 - p) (\mu_2^2 + \sigma_2^2)\\
M3 = p (\mu_1^3 + 3 \mu_1 \sigma_1^2) + (1 - p) (\mu_2^3 + 
     3 \mu_2 \sigma_2^2)\\
M4 = p (\mu_1^4 + 6 \mu_1^2 \sigma_1^2 + 3 \sigma_1^4) + (1 - 
     p) (\mu_2^4 + 6 \mu_2^2 \sigma_2^2 + 3 \sigma_2^4)
$$

Then define the central moments:
$$
MM4 = M4 - 4 M3 M1 + 6 M2 M1^2 + 3 M1^4\\
MM3 = M3 - 3 M1 M2 + 2 M1^3\\
MM2 = M2 - M1^2\\
MM1 = M1\\
$$

(NOTE: these equations are simply derived using the equation $MMn=E[(X-E[X])^n]$ and then simplifying)

Then I define the statistics I'm interested in and set them to the values I want, for example::
$$
kurtosis = \frac{MM4 - 3 MM2^2}{MM2^2} = 5\\
skewness = \frac{MM3}{MM2^{\frac{3}{2}}} = 3\\
variance = MM2 = 2\\
mean = MM1 = 0\\
$$

and then solve for $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\sigma_1$, and $\sigma_2$ (4 equations and 4 unknowns).

However, when I plug this into mathematica, it struggles to give me anything (ran for about an hour and then gave up).

I'm wondering if there is a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You might try with smaller skewness and excess kurtosis.  Even better, start with a known mixture, calculate the four statistics and see if they then give a solution consistent with what you started with

Comment: You may also have $p$ as a fifth unknown

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for the suggestions. As for $p$ as the fifth unknown, i was thinking the solutions would be functions of $p$... maybe that is an incorrect assumption